# jqGrid "_search" parameter is false all the time

Tags: jquery, jsp, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid in my code and have a little problem.
Here is the code from `asd.jsp`:

```
jQuery().ready(function ()
{

    $("#myGridId").jqGrid({
        url: "getListAsd.jsp",
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['menu', 'name', 'price'], 
        colModel: [
            {index: "menu", width: 250, sortable: true, editable: true, edittype: "text"},
            {index: "name", width: 250, sortable: true, editable: true, edittype: "text"},
            {index: "price", width: 100, sortable: true, editable: true, edittype: "text", align: "right"}
        ],
        rowNum: 35,
        height: 780,
        autowidth: false,
        sortname: "price",
        sortorder: "desc", 
        viewrecords: true,         
        pager: '#gridpager',
    })                
            .jqGrid('filterToolbar', { searchOnEnter: true, enableClear: true }) // make search available in each column
            .navGrid('#gridpager', {edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false, view: false},
                    {multipleSearch: true} // search options
            );
});
```

And here is the code from `getListAsd.jsp`:

```
if (request.getParameter("_search") != null) {
    search = java.lang.Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("_search"));
}
if (search) {
    // some search things here...
}
```

In gridpager I need `search: false` because I want to have search in each column and not using default search button.
So the problem is that `_search` is always false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.
It seems that jqGrid needs `name` attributes to perform search inside column correctly.
New code from `asd.jsp`:

```
colModel: [
        {name: "menu", index: "menu", width: 250, sortable: true, editable: true, edittype: "text"},
        {name: "name", index: "name", width: 250, sortable: true, editable: true, edittype: "text"},
        {name: "price", index: "price", width: 100, sortable: true, editable: true, edittype: "text", align: "right"}
    ],
```